# OPchache max keys cannot be changed

Tags: php, opcache

I want to increase the maximum number of cached keys in OPcache. As far as I understand this can be achieved by setting `opcache.max_accelerated_files` in the PHP settings.

However, the maximum number of cached keys always defaults to the initially configured value in `/etc/phpXX/conf.d/opcache.ini`.
It appears that the setting `opcache.max_accelerated_files` is properly parsed, but OPcache ignores it somehow.
What could be the cause of this issue?

Here are screenshots from the `phpinfo()`:
[PHP info: OPcache status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv570.png),
[PHP info: OPcache setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReDrf.png)

I understand that the maximum number of cached keys should be the first number in the set of prime numbers that is greater than or equal to the configured value. But this is not the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

You should check two things:

1. Enabling opcache. Check this line

   opcache.enable=1
2. Restart apache after changing your ‘.ini’ files
3. Change value of max accelerated files in your php.ini file (it value affects opcache settings)

Comment: This should be posted as a comment if asking for clarifications.

Comment: Yes as can be seen from the screenshot OPcache is up and running. The PHP FPM has also been reloaded/restarted (numerous times)

Comment: What returns opcache_get_configuration()?